# Can't execute batch file which msg command in it

Tags: windows, command, exec, msg

i have file named "msg.bat" and msg command in it

```
C:\Windows\system32\msg.exe * /server:X-PC test
```

when i execute it, X-PC pop out the message. But when i implement with the exec() command

```
exec("msg.bat");
```

it shows nothing. Do you guys have solution about this?

Comment: Do you mean the .bat does what you wnat but exec doesn't? Are you asking why?

Comment: I want exec() do the .bat does, i dont know how